# Dynamically generating HighCharts with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, highcharts

I have a SQL Server database with columns `ID`, `DateTime` and `Double`.

For example:

```
001 | 2014:06:30 10:25AM | 101.5
001 | 2014:06:30 10:26AM | 102.5
001 | 2014:06:30 10:27AM | 111.5
002 | 2014:06:30 10:27AM | 101.4
002 | 2014:06:30 10:28AM | 123.1
003 | 2014:06:30 10:29AM | 114.9
003 | 2014:06:30 10:30AM | 171.6
003 | 2014:06:30 10:31AM | 131.2
003 | 2014:06:30 10:31AM | 119.4
```

I want my highcharts to be a scatter chart with Datetime values as the X-Axis and the Double Values as the Y-Axis. These values are on individual series which are defined by the ID column (i.e Series 001 will have 3 points).

The problem I'm having is that the ID Column can change. Based on the users selection my query is adjusting. In one instance I can have 5 series (5 different ID's) and in the example above only 3 series.

I was wondering how to create the series in a loop which will loop based on the unique ID's and to pass in the x and y values as arrays.

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now and looked everywhere for a solution so anything helps at this moment. Currently I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and VB.Net with only a front and back end page. My data is in a MySQL Server where I'm already querying the values correctly based on user selection.

Comment: One of the problems is that you have incorrect data format. You should use epoch timestamps (time in miliseconds) for right working charts.

Answer (score 0):

You could have SQL Server construct and return the array as a string

```
Declare @Table table (id varchar(10),SomeDate varchar(25),SomeValue money)
Insert into @Table values
('001','2014:06:30 10:25AM',101.5),
('001','2014:06:30 10:26AM',102.5), 
('001','2014:06:30 10:27AM',111.5),
('002','2014:06:30 10:27AM',101.4), 
('002','2014:06:30 10:28AM',123.1), 
('003','2014:06:30 10:29AM',114.9), 
('003','2014:06:30 10:30AM',171.6), 
('003','2014:06:30 10:31AM',131.2), 
('003','2014:06:30 10:31AM',119.4)

 SELECT id, array = '['+STUFF((
    SELECT ',["' + SomeDate+'",'+cast(SomeValue as varchar(25))+']' FROM @Table
    WHERE id = x.id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
    +']'
FROM @Table AS x
GROUP BY ID
```

Returns

```
id  array
001 [["2014:06:30 10:25AM",101.50],["2014:06:30 10:26AM",102.50],["2014:06:30 10:27AM",111.50]]
002 [["2014:06:30 10:27AM",101.40],["2014:06:30 10:28AM",123.10]]
003 [["2014:06:30 10:29AM",114.90],["2014:06:30 10:30AM",171.60],["2014:06:30 10:31AM",131.20],["2014:06:30 10:31AM",119.40]]
```